# How to find if point is inside polygon in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I know there are manual ways of doing this (see [Point in Polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)), but is there a native way of determining whether a point is inside a polygon, in d3.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**: this is now part of [d3-polygon](https://github.com/d3/d3-polygon).

```
d3.polygonContains(polygon, point)
```

Comment: how to detect in which polygon the point lies in?

Answer (score 5):

Here's [an implementation](https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon), in case you'd rather not roll your own. Demo [here](http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe/5575904).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no function for this. The only very special case when there is support for this would be checking whether the point is the centroid of the polygon (using the `polygon.centroid` function), but in general you'll have to provide your own function.