# Can I cross-reference lat/lon coordinates with geoJSON data using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis

Let's say I am visualizing the US counties data provided by [us.json](https://gist.github.com/raw/4090846/b8c888f35c42400a080ab03c31a7649e0b9bc9a8/us.json)... if I'm given some lat/lon coordinates for a location, is it possible for me to cross-reference that with a county somehow using d3.js such that I can, for example, change the color of the county the location is in?

Comment: Do you have some additional information about the data format in the json file? Although it certainly looks valid and interesting, I don't have enough experience with the specific format to give a concrete answer to your question.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279165/how-to-find-if-point-is-inside-polygon-in-d3-js The answer is basically that you need to write your own function to do this; d3 doesn't provide anything for it.

Comment: I think that you can do that by transforming the given lat/lon coordinates to the coordinate system in the `us.json` file and then using [crossfilter](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/) to filter the county where your location is will allow you to change its color.

Comment: Any idea what coordinate system is being used in the example us.json file?